# Constructing system date

Tags: apex, soql, query, date

I have to pass year (in string) from VF into backend (apex) and make a query on objX with the condition that the year value should lie between start date and end date values on objX.

```
String startdatetime = selectedBPYear+'-01-01';
            String enddatetime = selectedBPYear+'-12-31';
            String startdatetime = selectedBPYear+'-01-01';
            Date mystartDate = Date.valueof(startdatetime);
            Date myendDate = Date.valueof(enddatetime);
            system.debug('&&&&'+myenddate);
            criteria += 'and Start_Date__c >=: mystartDate and End_Date__c <=: myendDate';
        }
        String newquery = 'Select Id, Name,Status__c From objX where Start_Date__c >=: mystartDate and End_Date__c <=: myendDate';
```

selectedBPYear is passed from VF to apex.The query is yielding no result. 
Is the date format constructed correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can make this simpler with the Date.newInstance() method and avoid the string constructions (assuming `selectedPbYear` is an integer)

```
   Date myStartDate = Date.newInstance(selectedPBYear,1,1);
   Date myendDate = Date.newInstance(selectedPBYear,12,31);

   String newquery = 'Select Id, Name,Status__c From objX where Start_Date__c >=: mystartDate and End_Date__c <=: myendDate';
```

If `selectedPbYear` is a string ..

```
Date myStartDate = Date.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(selectedPBYear),1,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Condition**: *the year value should lie between start date and end date values on objX*

**Solution**: SOQL date function [**CALENDAR_YEAR**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm)

**Example:**

```
--------|----------------|--------------|--------
Start_Date__c  <=  selectedBPYear >= End_Date__c
```

**SOQL:**

```
Where CALENDAR_YEAR(Start_Date__c) <= :selectedBPYear
And   CALENDAR_YEAR(End_Date__c)   >= :selectedBPYear
```

Comment: Why `>=` and `<=` the same value? If OP is looking for one specific year, just use `=`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson `year should lie between start and end` I think the OP is looking for the range of years. If start is 2000-01-01 and the end is 2015-01-01 and the given year is 2005 and it should lie between 2000 and 2015 so I will have to use greater/less or equal operators.

Comment: My interpretation is they are trying to go from `<year>-01-01` to `<year>-12-31` for one given year. If you interpret it differently, that may be legitimate, but you should update your code sample to use distinct year values so it makes more sense.